# Changing a Button's Click event based on a DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, button, datatrigger

I'm trying to change a Button's Click property/event when a DataTrigger is triggered but I'm not sure if this is the best method to do it. In fact, it won't even compile :)

What I have looks like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ObjectTreeView, Path=SelectedItem.Replaceable}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Add" />
            <Setter Property="Button.Click" Value="AddObject_Click" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ObjectTreeView, Path=SelectedItem.Replaceable}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Replace" />
            <Setter Property="Button.Click" Value="ReplaceObject_Click" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>            
</Style>
```

Compiling gives me an error message saying "Cannot find the Style Property 'Click' on the type 'System.Windows.Controls.Button'"

Any suggestions? If this not possible, what alternatives are there?

Thanks!

Edit:

I thought I found the solution which was to use an EventSetter, but EventSetters aren't supported inside Triggers. What I thought would've worked was:

```
<EventSetter Event="Button.Click" Handlder="AddObject_Click" />
```

But like I said, this is supported at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click isn't a property, it's an event.  Buttons have a property IsPressed that becomes true when the button is being pressed.  You could try using that.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be easier to just have one click event and in that event, an if statement based on your DataTrigger?

Comment: Sure. That's what I had before, but I'm looking for a xaml-based solution if possible.

Comment: I think what I'm looking for is an EventSetter.

Comment: And it looks like EventSetter isn't supported by Trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a Click event, try using the button's Command property. You should be able to switch which command it points to based on a Trigger.